# Delphi for .NET does not find shared files in the .NET library search directories ("[DCC Error] F1026 File not found)

Tags: asp.net, delphi, delphi-2007, file-not-found, delphi.net

I have been trying to track down a problem with an installation of RAD Studio 2007 for some time. When compiling an ASP.NET application build with the .NET personability, I get an "[DCC Error] F1026 File not found error, where it reports that it cannot find a particular .dcuil file.

The file that is referenced in this error message is located in a directory that appears in the .NET library search path. The only work around I found was to add the associated .pas file directly to the project.

I finally found a correct solution to this problem. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this problem can be found in the Quality Central posting 61394, which was originally submitted by Jordan Russell.

There is a bug in Delphi 2007 that prevents directories added to the .Net Library search path from being written to the EnvOptions.proj file. This does not appear to be a problem with the Win32 library search paths.

To solve the problem, manually edit the EnvOptions.proj file. On a typical Windows Vista install, this file is located in the C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Borland\BDS\5.0 directory, where *username* is the name of the user who installed RAD Studio 2007.

Begin by closing RAD Studio 2007. Then, open EnvOptions.proj in an editor (notepad.exe will do). Add the one or more directories that you want searched to the DotNetLibraryPath element. Directories appearing in this element must be separated with semicolons.